# Issue with Object with class instances

Tags: javascript

I have a holder object where I insert Class instances.

```
var instances = {};
$.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
    instances[value.platform.toLowerCase()] = new FetcherClass(value.platform, value.type, value.tempo, value.max);
});
```

**value.platform** is the name of the new instance.

All seems to works fine, but when I want to call a function within an instance, allways fires the function of the last instance.

For example:

instances.name1.start();

In case there are 'name1', 'name2' and 'name3' instances, the start() function fired belongs to 'name3' instance.

Here I post the output in console of Object 'instances'.

> Object name1 : FetcherClass nam2 : FetcherClass name3 : FetcherClass
>   name4 : FetcherClass name5 : FetcherClass name6 : FetcherClass name7 :
>   FetcherClass name8 : FetcherClass name9 : FetcherClass name10 :
>   FetcherClass
>   **proto** : Object

A link to an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8048w4cc/1/)

What's wrong?

Comment: Should there be a jQuery tag?

Comment: What are `FetcherClass` and `start` and `response.data`?

Comment: response.data is an Array of Objects from server. FetcherClass is an Object  which holds data & functions like start().

Comment: @Apalabrados You should include a [mcve]

Comment: @Oriol Here you are a link: https://jsfiddle.net/8048w4cc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an accidental global variable in _self. The first time the constructor is called, a new global variable called _SELF was created; subsequent calls to the constructor replaced it, such that all instances of the object referred to the most recent one.

Declare a variable within the constructor for FetcherClass and use that instead.

```js
    function FetcherClass(plataforma, type, interval, faults) {
        var SELF = this;
        SELF.PLATAFORMA = plataforma.toLowerCase();
        SELF.TYPE = type;
        SELF.INTERVAL = interval;
        SELF.MAX_INTENTOS = faults;

        SELF.start = function() {
            alert('I am '+SELF.PLATAFORMA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly!! I realized os such erro just before you mentioned it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem exists in the context of `_self`. If you use the variables directly, it works without an issues.

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8048w4cc/2/)

Comment: You gave me the clue. The problem was because _self is not a var within the scope of such Class, had global scope and that's the fault!

Comment: You've not addressed the accidental global - this will continue to be a problem in the code. You might want to merge my answer into yours.